# How do i link to new page after in app purchase

Tags: flutter

One the in app purchase has been  successful how to link it to the new page and make sure that the user doesn't have to pay twice for the same product.

Comment: Your question is very broad , you need to learn about back-end programming or ask your back-end programmer to prepare the server-side aspect. As for the link to check the outcome of purchase,  I assume you have built the purchase page with widgets, so you can use navigation and send the purchase data alongside with it.